# Local Memory Address Access

Tags: memory

Partitioned Global Address Space divides the memory into chunks of local memory to make access faster. My question: What are the reasons (maybe on a hardware level) access to local memory is faster? If I understand correctly, local memory is still at the address of the original shared memory address...

Answer (score 0):

> In computer science, a partitioned global address space (PGAS) is a parallel programming model. It assumes a global memory address space that is logically partitioned and a portion of it is local to each process, thread, or processing element.

If you refer to that, then it is just a model. The actual performance is dependent on the implementation.

## Local Implementation

If the implementation is "local", i.e., threads or processes inside the same machine (node), then there might be performance implication due to several reasons.

- First, the need to use synchronization will reduce the performance. Locks have a terrible implication on performance.
- Second, sharing the CPU's cache lines between cores, when at least one of the cores is writing to the cache line, will have to invalidate the cache line of all the other cores, which will induce an high performance penalty. Separating the working memory of each core, will prevent cache invalidation. Such method should be used if the application/algorithm enables it.

## Distributed Implementation

If the implementation is "distributed", i.e., [DSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory), then the penalty of accessing remote memory is even greater (but have similar sequence to the cache invalidation penalty) as a message have to send across the network.